# Building/Installing software with external dependencies on linux

Tags: linux, installation, libraries, dependencies

This kind of thing tends to happen to me more than it should. Often when I am building the source of some program or even just installing a program that has external dependencies that aren't already on my machine, I end up having to do countless Google searches to find what library I am actually missing.

A recent example is MathGL, which when I first tried to install it, it said it was missing some dependencies, but made no explicit mention that I needed to `apt-get install libmgl-dev`. Is this just common knowledge? I saw no mention of `libmgl-dev` in any of their README or INSTALL files or on their website. I even did a grep on the entire directory looking for a mention of `libmgl-dev`, and I found nothing. After much Google searching, I managed to find it on some forum post I looked at that said it was required.

There must be something wrong with my methodology. When installing anything, is there a standard way of determining what dependencies I need first? Many thanks!

Comment: The project **should** list there dependencies.  If they have an email or support area, tell them to update the list of dependencies.  Sometimes a library they do tell you about has additional dependencies of its own.  Sometimes people **assume** the package manager will figure it out, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the programming team is awesome and/or professional running
   **./configure** will tell you what is missing, sadly this kind of programming is the exception and not the rule.
2. when running make a (I forgot the exact error message) certain type of missing error message will be displayed.
3. Locating dependencies depends on the language in question.  Maybe someone else has a better way, but here is how I do it.  In the **C** programming language there are **include <** filename.h **>** statements that indicate header files.  If you search the current folders for the header file and can't find it, there is a chance it is part of another library.  Depending on the distro the standard headers files are in different locations.  In, OpenSuSE **/usr/include** contains all of the headers files for programs that have there **-dev** installed already.  If it is not in either place you are most likely missing a library you need to install.

In perl,  it is the **use** Something::subfunction **;** that indicates it is calling for and external module/library.

php has **include**, **include_once**, **require**, and **require_once** indicators.

Other languages have different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Most software will include a list of the dependencies it requires, although the list may not necessarily be in the most convenient form for you to find and install the them.

To take an arbitrary example, suppose you want to compile Gnumeric, the spreadsheet application.  You download the source code, and look in the file README, which has a section

```
Requirements
------------

You need:               Debian package name
    glib        >= 2.28.0   libglib2.0-dev
    gtk+        >= 3.2.0    libgtk3.0-dev
    libgsf      >= 1.14.24  libgsf-1-dev
    libgoffice  >= 0.10.1   libgoffice-0-8-dev
    gnome-xml       >= 2.4.12   libxml2-dev
    pango       >= 1.24.0   libpango1.0-dev
    NOTE: gnome-xml is also known as libxml

Optionally:
    python      >= 2.0      python-dev
    pygobject   >= 3.0.0    python-gi-dev

    The GDA plugin, for accessing databases
    gda     >= 1.3.0    libgda2-dev
    libgnomedb  >= 1.3.0    libgnomedb2-dev

Currently disabled:
    guile       >= 1.5  (no maintainer)

Runtime suggestions:
    'yelp' for help
```

Now this is the best case scenario, they tell you the required libraries, and the tell you the exact Debian package you need to install to get them.  For example, you would just run

```
$sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

to install the first dependency.

However, the second column of "debian package name" is not so common in most software packages.  Instead, they will just have the first column "glib",  and possibly a version number.  It is up to you to corroborate the named dependency "glib" with the debian (or ubuntu, etc) package name "libglib2.0-dev".  Usually some web or forum searches will help you find the package name.

With some experience, you will notice patterns in the names of the packages you need.  In general, libraries are packaged with names libXXXX, and in general they are separated into the runtime components (libXXX) and the development files needed to compile your program (libXXX-dev).  Beyond that, if you can't find the right package by a simple web search, look at the specific error message you get when you try to compile.  If for example, a file "glib.h" is missing, you can use your distribution's package search to find packages containing that file, or more generally you can always just search those error messages on the web to find other people with the same problem.

It's really up to the package how much information they give on the required dependencies, but the most common technique is to list the generic name of the library needed.  The person compiling the package is then responsible for figuring out how to install the development files for that library on their specific system configuration.

If you find software that *doesn't* list its dependencies in any way, then file a bug report, and in the meantime, get prepared to start slogging through some error messages.